# How to obtain one word preceded by specific word in shell

Tags: bash, file, shell, parsing

I have a text file containing something like this:

> dn: domain.com
>
> uid: user
>
> dn: domain.com
>
> uid:
>   user2

Now, I want to get **only** user and user2. Without *uid* tag.

How could I do it in shell bash?

I thought about `sed` command, but I'm not sure if there is an easiest way to do it.

Comment: Yes use sed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try : `awk '/uid:/{print $2}' text_file.txt`

Comment: Thank you. Didnt thought of `awk` command. It works perfectly.